# C++ transform parameter initialization question

Tags: c++, transform, tolower

I was trying to transform a string into lowercase and store it in another variable using `std::transform` and `std::tolower`. I first tried:

```
string str1("Hello");
string lowerStr1;
transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), lowerStr1.begin(), ::tolower);
cout << lowerStr1 << endl;
```

But, `lowerStr1` contained nothing. After initializing `lowerStr1` with `str1`, I got the desired result. I want to know the intuition behind this. Could someone explain why `lowerStr1` should be initialized in this case?

Comment: In addition to the problem you're struggling with, see [the notes here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) on why you want to cast the argument for `tolower` to an `unsigned char`. It's a problem you probably won't encounter, but when you do it's an absolute mind <expletive deleted>  if you don't know it's coming.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lowerStr1` is empty, and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) won't insert elements into it.

> `std::transform` applies the given function to a range and stores the result in another range, beginning at `d_first`.

You can use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which constructs a [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), which would call `push_back()` on the container to insert elements.

```
transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), back_inserter(lowerStr1), ::tolower);
```

Or make `lowerStr1` containing 5 elements in advance.

```
string lowerStr1(5, '\0');
transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), lowerStr1.begin(), ::tolower);
```

or

```
string lowerStr1;
lowerStr1.resize(5);
transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), lowerStr1.begin(), ::tolower);
```

> Could someone explain why `lowerStr1` should be initialized in this case?

That's because you initialize `lowerStr1` containing 5 elements in advance as above. What's the value of the initialized elements doens't matter in fact.

Comment: Makes so much more sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your call to `std::transform` is logically equivalent to the following code:

```
auto b=str1.begin();
auto e=str1.end();
auto p=lowerStr1.begin();

while (b != e)
{
       *p=tolower(*b);
       ++b;
       ++e;
}
```

But `lowerStr1`, is a completely empty string. `lowerStr1.begin()` gives you, loosely speaking, a pointer to an empty string. So writing to that pointer and, adding insult to injury, incrementing it and continuing to write to it, result in undefined behavior, memory corruption, and a non-trivial possibility of a crash.

You do not add content to an empty string by grabbing a pointer to it, and then scribbling into that pointer. There are several ways of doing that correctly, with `push_back`() or `insert`() methods. You can also use an iterator that does that, like a [std::back_insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), which can use with `std::transform`.

Answer (score 0):

Generic algorithms won't change the size of the containers.
You need to use an iterator adapter which implements `operator=` in a special way so that it actually insert elements.
Therefore you can use `back_inserter(lowerStr1)` to make sure that `lowerStr1` gets extended as `trasform()` does assignments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str1("Hello");
  string lowerStr1;
  transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), std::back_inserter(lowerStr1), ::tolower);
  cout << lowerStr1 << endl;
}
```